# Prove that forall prime number $p$ we can find $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p|P(n)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For $P(x)=(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-6)$ Prove that forall prime number $p$ we can find $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p|P(n)$.

Comment: I want to find elementary solution for this problem

Answer (score 4):

Since $2|P(2)$ and $3|P(3)$, the assertion is trivial for $p=2$ and $p=3$.
Assume $p>3$.
Since the Legendre symbol is multiplicative, we have $(6|p)=(2|p)(3|p)$, hence if $2$ and $3$ are not quadratic residue modulo $p$, then $6$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ and consequently $P$ has a root in $\Bbb F_p$.